# How do I stop a crated dog from barking?

Tags: dogs, behavior, vocalizations, crate

We recently rescued our dog (6-12 months old), who was very undernourished and slept quite often. As we've done with other pets, we attempted to crate train him. At first, it didn't appear that he had any issue with the crate and would not bark or show any signs of distress.

This changed once we took him to the vet for the first time. He received some pills and vaccinations to prepare him for the being around other dogs. That night, he began barking quite loudly in his crate for 10-15 minutes before giving up and going to sleep.

Is it possible that the vet gave him some type of medicine that could have caused this change in behavior? Or, is this behavior symptomatic of his health quality increasing, and with that, additional energy to express his distaste for being crated?

No matter what the reason, are there any suggestions for dealing with this behavior?

Comment: No, you're doing everything right. 10-15 minutes is good.

Comment: I think he's just getting more attached to you and as a consequence being close to you all the time is becoming more important for him. He'll probably stop as soon as he realises barking does not get him out of the crate.

Comment: Wanted to follow up - the pup now sleeps through the night without any barking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened once and lasted 10-15 minutes?  If so, it's normal and just coincidence that it followed a vet visit. Nothing the vet gave him had anything to do with it. A puppy of that age is likely to holler a bit before giving up and going to sleep.  Unless it becomes a chronic problem it's nothing to worry about.

My suggestion for dealing with it is what you've already done.  Just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, giving them a soft toy a plush animal for example, with your scent in it did wonders for me!

28 Years old
Lived with and helped raise 7 Boston Terriers

Comment: You probably don't want to give a 6-12 month old puppy who seems to be distressed in his cage a soft toy... He'll rip it up.